# Запуск функции из адаптера

Tags: android, функции, kotlin, google-maps-api, android-intent

Написал адаптер. Адаптер генерирует RecyclerView. Не могу найти инфу как при нажатии на элемент RecyclerView сделать так, чтобы передавалась определённая инфа из адаптера в функцию из Main и запускалась.

Вот Адаптер:

```
package com.arekok.ink.apteka.pharmacyNew

import ...

class PharmacyAdapter(
    var c: Context, var pharmacyList:ArrayList<PharmacyData>
): RecyclerView.Adapter<PharmacyAdapter.PharmacyViewHolder>()
{
    inner class PharmacyViewHolder(var v: PharmacyItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v.root){}
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PharmacyViewHolder {
        val inflter = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val v = DataBindingUtil.inflate<PharmacyItemBinding>(
            inflter, R.layout.pharmacy_item,parent,
            false)
        return PharmacyViewHolder(v)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PharmacyAdapter.PharmacyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val newList = pharmacyList[position]
        holder.v.isPharmacy = pharmacyList[position]

        ///   Check time ///
        val end = newList.end
        val start = newList.start
        val currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
        val data = currentDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.SHORT))
        if (data < end.toString() && data > start.toString()){
            holder.v.imageStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.open)
        } else {
            holder.v.imageStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.close)
        }
        ////////////////////


        holder.v.root.setOnClickListener {
            val name = newList.name
            val work = newList.work
            val end = newList.end
            val start = newList.start
            val loc1 = newList.loc1
            val loc2 = newList.loc2
            val location = newList.location
            MainActivity().addMark(loc1!!,loc2!!)
        }

    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return  pharmacyList.size
    }
}
```

И функция из Main

```
fun addMark(loc1: Double, loc2: Double) {
        val apt = LatLng(loc1, loc2)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(apt).title("test"))
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для таких целей можно использовать interface между активностью и адаптером. Создаем например такой interface:

```
interface DataUpdater {
    fun addMarkFun(loc1: Double, loc2: Double)
}
```

дальше в конструктор адаптера добавляем данный интерфейс:

```
class PharmacyAdapter(
    var c: Context, var pharmacyList:ArrayList<PharmacyData>,
    var dataSender:DataUpdater
): RecyclerView.Adapter<PharmacyAdapter.PharmacyViewHolder>()
{
```

добавляем передачу данных при нажатии:

```
holder.v.root.setOnClickListener {
            ....
            dataSender.addMarkFun(loc1!!,loc2!!)
        }
```

дальше переходим и добавляем данный интерфейс в активности:

```
class MainActivity():AppCompatActivity, DataUpdater{
...
```

вам будет предложено переопределить метод из интерфейса:

```
override fun openJob(
        loc1: Double, 
        loc2: Double
    ) {
        addMark(loc1, loc2)
    }
```

а при создании адаптера нужно будет добавить параметр:

```
PharmacyAdapter(...,this)
```

по логике должно работать. Вот есть хороший [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56826346/kotiln-pass-data-from-adapter-to-activity) который похож на мой ответ как можно заметить)

Comment: Помогло! Спасибо за помощь, очень благодарен!